# AngularJS route helper

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

Any ideas how to build solution, that helps generate url in view in more convenient way, instead of hard-coding like that:

```
<a ng-href="#/Book/{{item.bookId}}/ch/{{item.id}}">Chapter {{item.id}}</a>
```

I want to use:

```
<a chapters="[item.bookId, item.id]">Chapter {{item.id}}</a>
```

So it checks routes and generates for each route specific directive.

I'm interested in the most generic solution as possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would highly recommend you make use of ui-router, and its `$stateProvider`.

```
var app = angular.module('yourModuleName', ['ui.router']);

app.config(function ($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('book', {
      url: '/Book/:bookId'
    })
    .state('book.chapter', {
      url: '/ch/:id'
    });
});

<a ui-sref="book.chapter({bookId: item.bookId, id: item.id})">Chapter {{item.id}}</a>
```

Something along those lines should do the trick. I'm not at all familiar with the other parameters of your application, but building dynamic URL's with passed in parameters to match up with a `$state` is a breeze.

ui-router: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

ui-sref (directive): https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can use Angular-UI 
[Angular-UI/UI-Router](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/)

The main idea in there is to have states because you have single page app and everything are just state who renders in single place. No refresh nothing.

When integrating it you can create

```
$stateProvider
      .state("bookPreview", {
        url: "/book/:id/:itemId",
        controller: "BookPreviewCtrl",
        templateUrl: 'sb/add-cpe-template.tpl.html'
      });
```

In your html you  can do the following thing:

```
<button ng-click="view(item.bookId, item.id)">Chapter {{item.id}}</button>
```

or something like that, you can assign ng-click on hyperlinks as well.

The java script view function is:(but before you must inject $

```
controller("BookSelectionCtrl",function($scope,$state){

  //this will rewrite the url , go to the state and load the template(view).
  $scope.view=function(bookId,itemId){
    $state.go("bookPreview",{id:bookId,itemId:itemId}) //there is a third object representing options, which are optional and you can check them on doc site
  }   

})

controller("BookPreviewCtrl",function($scope,$stateParams){
   //in this new ctrl of the new view you can now do what ever you want with these params
   $scope.bookId = $stateParams.id;
   $scope.itemId = $stateParams.itemId; 
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop over all routes and build directives dynamically, here is a start http://plnkr.co/edit/d592a58CMan5BVKQYSAy?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$route) {
  var keys = [];
  for(var k in $route.routes) keys.push(k);
  $scope.name = keys;
  for (var i=0; i<keys.length; ++i) {
    app.directive('SomethingDynamic', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        template: '....',
      };
    });
  }
});

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
    when('/complex/:name/:color/:number/extra', {
      templateUrl: "404.html",
      name:'complex'
    }).
    when('/objects', {
      templateUrl: "404.html",
      name:'list'
    }).
    when('/object/detail/:id', {
      templateUrl: "404.html",
      name:'detail'
    });
});
```

Comment: Looking good, but how can I extract code from particular controller?

Comment: I didn't get your question, what code are you referring to ?

Comment: I mean all code in `MainCtrl`. May be create provider that would generate all directives?

Comment: You can put that code any where in your app, it only should be executed on start. A root Controller may be good

Answer (score 1):

Or you can create directive ([jsbin](http://jsbin.com/muvegupu/2/edit)):

View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">

<book-link book="book" ng-repeat="book in books"></book-link>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module("app",[])
.controller("mainCtrl", function($scope){

  var books = [
    {bookId : "book1", id:"1" },
    {bookId : "book1", id:"2" },
    {bookId : "book1", id:"3" }
  ];

  $scope.books = books;


})

.directive("bookLink",function(){

  return {
    restrict:"E",
    scope:{book:'='},
    template:"<a href='/book/{{book.bookId}}/ch/{{book.id}}'>Chapter {{book.id}}</a><br/>"

  };

});
```